# On-Board Charger Battery Load

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I am designing an On board charger for electric vehicles for my graduation project. And I am confused about testing the OBC. My goal is charging a 400V battery pack, but I don't have a battery pack and probably I won't.

Is it enough to use resistors instead of batteries? If not what can I use for equivalent to battery?

Comment: Depends on your requirements. If it's the bulk power transfer you are concerned about, a resistor will most likely suffice. If it's the charging characteristics, CC to CV transition, end of charge termination, SOC estimations and so on, then no. What's your scope?

Comment: @winny . Yes It is gonna be a bulk power transfer. I am not interesting in battery side estimations. I want to make estimation about efficiency of charger for example. And there will be PFC stage too.

Comment: Then it's most likely good enough. I would mention it early in the report though under "limitations" or a similar chapter in case anyone brings it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To measure power capabilities of charger:**
Yes, the resistors will be enough, because they will give you the opportunity to load the charger with the same current as in the real application.
EDIT: And as I just saw in the comments to the question: Yes, estimation of power efficiency will also be possible.

**To measure behaviour during real charging process:**
No, the resistors won't emulate a real charging process but be just a constant load. The charger won't be able to detect a progress in charging state and can't adjust to that.

Does your lab have a programmable electronic load? If yes, you can use that to simulate the charging process of the batteries and by that verify the behaviour of the charger.